# Plugin stable tag on wordpress.org not updating

Tags: plugins

What am I doing wrong?

It should be at version 1.4 now, but is still at 1.1.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wk-google-analytics/

Comment: Do you mean you can't install the latest version on your site or are you the plugin author and you are having trouble updating the repository?  If the first, you might find it best to ask at the plugin's support channels.  If the second, then you might find it best to ask at wordpress.org.

Comment: I am the author of this plugin and have email plugins@wordpress already without answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read-me.txt show a stable tag to 1.3 that you must edit in the trunk folder to be 1.4. At this time, the read-me tell I'm with a stable tag of 1.3 so go in the folder tags/1.3, and the wk-ga.php show a value of version 1.1.

You need to change the version number in wk-ga.php in your tags directory, according to the trunk (and tag too) read-me file.

Comment: I have edit the stable tag of EVERY tag? I thought only the readme stable tag in the trunk folder counts

Comment: Yes of course, only in the stable tag folder.